# Using audio from youtube videos without the player visible

Tags: youtube

I want to embed certain videos from youtube on my site but I only need the audio from them so I want to set the iframe to `display:none` and use the api to control the play and pause with custom buttons. Is this breaking any rules?

Answer (score 1):

Think about it. Why would Youtube let you use its content and infrastructure if they are hidden? The ads will not show and neither will the suggest videos at the end to direct visitors back to more stuff Youtube. You may have a great idea to use the audio for but unless it also benefits them, expect to be on your own.

While this is the my intuition, here is the official statement from [Youtube's term of service](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms):

> If you use the Embeddable Player on your website, you may not modify,
>   build upon, or block any portion or functionality of the Embeddable
>   Player, including but not limited to links back to the YouTube
>   website.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the display:none will not work as the browser will not start the plugin nor the audio.